# Why isn't my SelectCountMethod getting called?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ado.net, objectdatasource

I'm binding a `GridView` to a `ObjectDataSource`.

I'm expecting the `m_ObjectDataSourceGrid_Selected` method to fire twice, once for the Select and again for the Count, but it only fires once.

What's going on?

```
<asp:GridView ID="m_GridViewDocClasses" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="m_ObjectDataSourceGrid" 
            AllowSorting="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DocClass.aspx?DocClassId={0}"
                    Text="Edit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />                    
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="m_ObjectDataSourceGrid" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetDocClasses"
        TypeName="SouthernCompany.Generation.SPORT.Business.DocClassBL" OnObjectCreating="m_ObjectDataSourceGrid_ObjectCreating"
        OnSelected="m_ObjectDataSourceGrid_Selected" SelectCountMethod="GetDocClassesCount"
        SortParameterName="sort">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="sort" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="startRowIndex" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="maximumRows" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="docClassId" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What is `Count`?

Comment: Count is the count, meaning, the value I expect to get from `e.ReturnValue` when m_ObjectDataSourceGrid_Selected fires the second time.

Comment: Weird, didn't you just answer here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915555/how-do-i-tell-if-the-objectdatasource-onselected-event-was-called-for-the-selectm/5997878#5997878 , that it was getting fired twice?

Comment: Does the gridview have the AllowPaging set to true? Can you show some code?

Comment: @itchi, I did answer there.  That is the code I'm using in other apps, but it's not working here and I don't know why.  I know I could just get the count myself in the DataBound method, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not because you haven't assigned allowpaging, put these three:

```
AllowPaging="true" 
AllowSorting="true"
PageSize="25"
```

AllowPaging is needed to call the SelectCountMethod.

remove allowsorting if not needed.

Comment: Also, `EnablePaging="true"` on the ObjectDataSource

Answer (score 2):

Does your SelectCountMethod is receiving the same parameters as SelectMethod? There's two ways that makes SelectCountMethod acceptable: without any parameter "()" or with the same parameters as SelectMethod, besides Sorting and Paging parameters.

Comment: SelectMethod and SelectCountMethod both receive the same 4 parameters.